# How to make the data only available for one time on firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I want to make a report that can only apply by one user for one day only, so the user can't post double record on the same date.
Here is the code

// I use ionic and firebase

this is the code for the html

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>laporanharian</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>
          <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD YY" [(ngModel)]="myDate" #mydate></ion-datetime>
          
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Porsi Karbohidrat</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="number" #porsiKarbohidrat></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Porsi Protein Hewani</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="number" #porsiProteinHewani></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label floating>Porsi Protein Nabati</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="number" #porsiProteinNabati></ion-input>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item>
              <ion-label floating>Porsi Lemak</ion-label>
              <ion-input type="number" #porsiLemak></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
    
    </ion-list>
    <button ion-button full (click)="submitLaporan()">Submit</button>

</ion-content>
```

and this is the code for ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams,AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';

/**
 * Generated class for the LaporanharianPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@Component({
  selector: 'page-laporanharian',
  templateUrl: 'laporanharian.html',
})
export class LaporanharianPage {

  
  myDate: String = new Date().toISOString();
  id : string;

  constructor(private alertctrl :AlertController ,private db : AngularFireDatabase,public fire :AngularFireAuth,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  @ViewChild('mydate') mydate;
  @ViewChild('porsiKarbohidrat') porsiKarbohidrat;
  @ViewChild('porsiProteinHewani') porsiProteinHewani;
  @ViewChild('porsiProteinNabati') porsiProteinNabati;
  @ViewChild('porsiLemak') porsiLemak;

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LaporanharianPage');
  }
  alert(message : string)
  {
    this.alertctrl.create({
      title: 'info !',
      subTitle: message,
      buttons: ['OK']
    }).present();
  }

  submitLaporan()
  {
    
    this.id = this.fire.auth.currentUser.uid;
    this.db.list('/laporan/'+this.id).push({
      mydate : this.mydate.value,
      porsiKarbohidrat : this.porsiKarbohidrat.value,
      porsiProteinHewani : this.porsiProteinHewani.value,
      porsiProteinNabati : this.porsiProteinNabati.value,
      porsiLemak : this.porsiLemak.value,
    })

    this.alert("Sukses")
    }

    

}
```

I just use the standar code to push the data to firebase.
With this code I can upload report double on the same day.

Comment: save the date in your dataBase and check in the server side if today>this date

Comment: how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check Firebase for existing reports which are newer than one day (in milliseconds). If there is a rapport, permit inserting a new one.

Method to filter reports from Firebase:

```
const yesterday = Date.now() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

db
  .list<Report>('/laporan/' + this.id)
  .valueChanges()
  .map(reports => reports.filter(report => report.mydate > yesterday))
  .subscribe(reports => {
    if (reports.length === 0) {
      // insert report in Firebase
    }

    console.log(reports);
});
```

Note: `mydate` = milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC.